# Xamarin Forms Listview selected item background color is lost when setting the background color for the list view item template and list bg color

Tags: xamarin.forms

why is the Xamarin Forms Listview selected item background color is lost when setting the background color for the list view item template and list Background color ?

**XAML**

```
<ListView x:Name="CorrecpondencesListView"   
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Correspondences}"  
                  HasUnevenRows="True" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                  ItemSelected="OnSelectSingleCorrecpondences"    
                  SeparatorColor="{StaticResource lightGrey}"
                  IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" 
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource DynamicBackgroundColor}"
                  Refreshing="ListView_Refreshing">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:CustomViewCell SelectedItemBackgroundColor="#F3F3F3" >
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <Grid Padding="10,10,10,10" RowSpacing="2" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource DashboardItemsDarkSurface}">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </controls:CustomViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Add your code so we will identify what are you doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks sir for your response, what happened is that I have been setting the background color for the ListView and it's item template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue fixed when I have stopped to set the ListView Background Color.